# TextFormField cannot be typed in when text in controller is set or cleared

Tags: android, flutter

I have a `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
    controller: nameController,
    style: TxtStyles.input,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 6)),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        hintText: 'Your name (example: Mitsuha)',
        hintStyle: TxtStyles.hint,
        labelText: 'Name',
        errorText: state.status == Status.error ? 'Error' : null),
    onChanged: (value) => { validate(context) },
)
```

`TxtStyles` is just a custom `TextStyle` declared in other places. The problem is that whenever I set a value or clear controller:

```
 nameController.text = '';
```

or

```
 nameController.text = 'Gudetama'; 
 //Gudetama would appear, but field cannot be edited at all
```

or

```
 nameController.clear();
```

Wherever it is, nothing can then be typed inside it. When I tapped on it, it changed to that default blue color, meaning it got focused, but no keys I typed appeared in it. What's the problem?

I ran the app on android emulator.

-------------- SOLVED

Problem is with `onChanged` indeed. What's inside `validate(context)` is a call to BLoC event:

```
void validate(BuildContext ctx) {
    setState(() {
      ctx.read<NewNameBloc>().add(Validate(nameController.text, ageController.text));
    });
}
```

This is what it does in BLoC block:

```
if (event is Validate) {
      emit(state.copyWith(isEnable: (event.name.isNotEmpty && event.age.isNotEmpty));
}
```

I removed the BLoC call and changed it to:

```
void validate() {
  setState(() {
    isBtnEnabled = nameController.text.isNotEmpty && ageController.text.isNotEmpty;
    //isBtnEnabled is a variable inside widget's state
  });
}
```

And finally it worked, wherever it is I put `clear()` or `nameController.text = ''`, it can then be typed in again after that. I still don't know why it happened though...

Comment: Probably have something to do with your validate(context) method, could you provide code for that part?

Comment: When are you setting the values? In the init state??

Comment: @LeeBoonKong Thanks for the pointer! I checked it and it's indeed the problem, I've changed the inside of that method. It's solved, but I've edited this question with more code in case you still wanna see what's inside validate

Comment: @Konayuki No Problems~ Glad I could help you